# Bootstrap example do not show properly in Laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I installed **Laravel** **5.8.32** version and got bootstrap example of navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

This code in file navbar.blade.php.
In main file(index.blade.php) code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
        <title>Examplee</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @include('navbar')

    </body>
</html>
```

Output example:https://i.stack.imgur.com/owMe0.jpg

But result is not proper please help me.Thanks in advanse!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "not proper result" and one of the folder structure of your `resources/views` folders and subfolders?

Comment: @mdexp it says I have not enough reputation to post image.To simplicity I put navbar file in same folder with index.blade.php

Comment: Okay, you could as well upload the image to imgur manually and share the link in the post. By the way, are you rendering the index view through a controller, right? Can you post that code as well?

Comment: Can you post the developer console output (as code or screenshot)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the right stylesheet and script tags?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

More info on setting up Bootstrap can be found under the documentation here:
[Bootstrap 4.3 Getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: I put but did not help.